# What is Quality Assurance's role in a company that practices Continuous Delivery?

Tags: qa, continuous-delivery

[I was listening to this podcast on Continuous Delivery](http://www.se-radio.net/2015/02/episode-221-jez-humble-on-continuous-delivery/) and Jez Humble briefly talked about QA's role, but I didn't really get a "big picture" idea of they're doing on a day to day basis.  How is their job description changed when a company practices Continuous Delivery?

Comment: By QA do you mean quality or test?  QA has a big part to play in CI as they monitor and refine the processes that ensure quality. Test also has a part to play but do more work further upstream of where they traditionally work

Answer (score 5):

There are some things which a CI environment can't effectively check. Or things which are cost prohibitive to implement in a CI build process.

For example, I work with embedded systems which run on all manner of physical machines. It is incredibly difficult and frankly impossible to perfectly model the entire physical machine for all possibilities virtually.

The specific hardware combinations alone cause issues. The physical connections between different components may cause issues. Disk write speed on "virtual" systems vs the deployment system may change, resulting in different failures.

CI can do a great job on testing individual pieces of a large system to verify they work correctly. But writing a comprehensive "perfectly replicate your product in a CI test environment" simulator/emulator simply is not possible in some cases.

So a QA department can add a lot of value in situations like this.

If it's possible to develop a CI system to completely and comprehensively test all your processes, you may benefit from moving all your testing to CI and have a lower need of QA. But in many applications this is quite non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your QA team's primary responsibility is in maintaining relevant acceptance tests. That means they spend most of their time coming up with clever ways to break the application, codifying those cases, and periodically pruning away obsolete or less helpful cases.

Beyond that, there *are* things that an automated suite can't test, which require an experienced QA and/or editorial and/or UX person's eye:

- Does the UI look nice?
- Is the UI/UX intuitive?
- Are the graphics on the page helpful or distracting?
- Is the language in paragraph X relevant and easy to ready?

Beyond that, it can be difficult to codify a singular automated test suite for functionality that crosses application or platform boundaries. For instance, a test runner may be designed to automate browser interactions, but not native applications. In that case, if the related native applications are pretty slender on functionality, it may be simpler to have a QA person spend 10 or 20 minutes to ensure the integration still functions.

Comment: I feel that those bullet points are not the things that QA is responsible for.  Rather it is a UX/UI designer's responsibility.  At least traditionally.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Yeah. I'd argue that they're cross-functional concerns. A UI/UX person would certainly design the experience. But, I don't see UX concerns being outside the domain of "Quality" either. But, it depends on the organization.

Comment: Maintaining tests is a validation and verification teams role. QA is responsible for making sure the business goals are achieved.

Comment: @mattnz acceptance tests don't ensure business goal satisfaction?

Comment: ... I guess I'm not sure it's a relevant question, in any case. "QA" clearly has a variety of interpretations here...

Comment: My point is if you are using QA to test, your not doing QA, you are doing test. Ensuring the tests are done, (after determining if they need to be done) is a QA role, but actually doing them, and/or doing nothing else, is not QA, its Test.

Comment: @mattnz well, maybe. In either case, in the absence of an automated test environment, that generally means qa is executing manual acceptance tests.